# Xubuntu doesnt show user on login screen

Tags: xubuntu

It is Xubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

On the welcome screen:

[image: picture1]

When I click black triangle button to expand list of users I see some of them and some others are not there. Of course I can click "Other" and log into user not listed but it is frustrating me.

I did go through `launcher-> Users and groups` but I can only add/delete user/group - It doesnt change the list seen on welcome screen.

I might assume that Xubuntu is trimming the list of 'visible' users when list is too big but is there a way to force which users is listed and which ones are not?

Comment: check the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. string `greeter-hide-users=false` should be uncommented

Comment: Based on ur post I did go through https://wiki.debian.org/LightDM but it didnt work. There is no place when I can choose which users are seenable,   neither it shows all users.
Of course I did restart my xubuntu so new settings are taken into account.